# PHP Login not registering data in database

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $userid = $_POST["userid"];
    $pword = $_POST["pword"];

    # session

    session_start();

    # check that session is valid and set

    if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
    {
        header('Location: login.php');
    }

    # check that the required values have been entered
    $testin1 = ($userid);
    $testin2 = ($pword);

    if($testin1 == "") 
    {
        print "<hr><h1> No Username Entered, Please return to the Login page</h1></hr>";
    }
    elseif ($testin2 == "") 
    {
        print "<hr><h1> No Password Entered, Please return to the Login page</h1></hr>";
    }

    # Connect to database

    $connect = mysql_connect ("localhost","root") or die("Error Connecting to SQLServer"); 
    $db = mysql_select_db ("test");

    # query  

      $query = mysql_query ("select username from login where username = '$userid' and pword = '$pword';");

    if($query === FALSE) 
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $record = $result['username'] ;

    if ($record != null) 
    # check if session is operational, if so redirect the user to the correct page    
    {
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
    }
    else if ($record == null) 
    {
        header( 'Location: login.php' );
    }
?>
```

Does anyone know where this is not functioning? It seems to be 'error free' however keeps redirecting me back to the login.php page as opposed to the index.php page. any help would be great as i am a relative novice in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you put some print statements in and you could find out exactly where it is failing.  And tell us exactly what is happening when you try to log in.

Comment: Are you sure your session variable is set ? echo $_SESSION['login'] and check if it is set or not

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated. Instead use `mysqli` or `PDO`. However, You have `if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
{ header('Location: login.php');
}` at the beginning of index.php - that means that You always would be redirected as this session property is not set.

Comment: can you paste the code in index.php , I guess there might be an issue there . According to me you will be checking whether the user has logged in with in the index.php also and redirecting him to login.php

Comment: If that code You provided is a login.php file, remove that `if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) { header('Location: login.php'); }` from the start as this is not needed here at login page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might possible be outputting data to the user before the `header()` is output. You have `<HR>`s and output (I know that it is only if there is an error) but if you are using those, you could well have `<HTML>` and the like above the code.

If that is the case, then no other header will function.

(Posting as answer as too long for comment - and might be the issue.

Try this code:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $userid = $_POST["userid"];
    $pword = $_POST["pword"];

    // check that the required values have been entered
    $testin1 = ($userid);
    $testin2 = ($pword);

    if($testin1 == "") 
    {
        print "<hr><h1> No Username Entered, Please return to the Login page</h1></hr>";
    }

    if ($testin2 == "") 
    {
        print "<hr><h1> No Password Entered, Please return to the Login page</h1></hr>";
    }

    // Connect to database

    $connect = mysql_connect ("localhost","root") or die("Error Connecting to SQLServer"); 
    $db = mysql_select_db ("test");

    // query  

      $query = mysql_query ("select username from login where username = '$userid' and pword = '$pword';");

    if($query === FALSE) 
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $record = $result['username'] ;

    if ($record != null) 
    // check if session is operational, if so redirect the user to the correct page    
    {
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
    }
    else if ($record == null) 
    {
        header( 'Location: login.php' );
    }
?>
```

I looked through and moved a few things around as well as modifying the logic ever so slightly.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `mysql_fetch_array().`  In order to access a result by the key you need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc().`

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
  $record = $result['username'] ;
```

Keep in mind that it is always best to escape any user input with mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: The default for fetch_array is actually BOTH a number and assoc array:  `array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your session, check $_SESSION['login'] whether it is set or not, because you are checking if !isset() then you are redirecting to login.php page.
 Just verify the session variable by debugging your code